# Rich Snippets : Microdata itemprop out of the itemtype?

Tags: microdata, rich-snippets

I've recently decided to update a website by adding rich snippets - microdata.
The thing is I'm a newbie to this kind of things and I'm having a small question about this.

I'm trying to define the Organization as you can see from the code below:

```
<div class="block-content" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<p itemprop="name">SOME ORGANIZATION</p>
<p itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<span itemprop="streetAddress">Manufacture Street no 4</span>, 
<span itemprop="PostalCode">4556210</span><br />
<span itemprop="addressLocality">CityVille</span>, 
<span itemprop="addressCountry">SnippetsLand</span></p>
<hr>
<p itemprop="telephone">0444 330 226</p>
<hr>
<p><a href="mailto:info@snippets.com" itemprop="email">info@snippets.com</a></p>
</div>
```

Now, my problems consists in the following: I'd like to also tag the LOGO in order to make a complete Organization profile, but the logo stands in the header of my page, and the div I've posted above stands in the footer and the style/layout of the page doesnt permit me to add the logo in here and also make it visible.

So, how can I solve this thing? What's the best solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan, you could simply add in the logo schema with this code:

```
<img itemprop="logo" src="http://www.example.com/logo.png" />
```

So in your example, you could simply tag it as:

```
<div class="block-content" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<p itemprop="name">SOME ORGANIZATION</p>
<img itemprop="logo" src="http://www.example.com/logo.png" />
<p itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<span itemprop="streetAddress">Manufacture Street no 4</span>, 
<span itemprop="PostalCode">4556210</span><br />
<span itemprop="addressLocality">CityVille</span>, 
<span itemprop="addressCountry">SnippetsLand</span></p>
<hr>
<p itemprop="telephone">0444 330 226</p>
<hr>
<p><a href="mailto:info@snippets.com" itemprop="email">info@snippets.com</a></p>
</div>
```

I believe that should work for your particular case and it won't actually show the logo and you wouldn't have to mark up the logo separately.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks David. I already found a way : microdata has elements that are hidden by default, they're called ``<meta />``. Still, I've accepted your question because it is another variant that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`itemref` attribute](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/52592/17633).

Give your logo in the header an `id` and add the corresponding `itemprop`:

```
<img src="acme-logo.png" alt="ACME Inc." itemprop="logo" id="logo" />
```

Now add `itemref="logo"` to your `div` in the footer:

```
<div class="block-content" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemref="logo">
  …
</div>
```

---

If this is not possible in your case, you could "duplicate" the logo so that it’s included in your `div`, but not visible. Microdata allows `meta` and `link` elements in the `body` for this case. You should use the `link` element, as [`http://schema.org/Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) expects an URL for the [`logo` property](http://schema.org/logo). (Alternatively, add it via `meta` as a separate [ImageObject](http://schema.org/ImageObject)).

```
<div class="block-content" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  …
  <link itemprop="logo" src="logo.png" />
  …
</div>
```

---

Side note: I don’t think that you are using the [`hr` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element) correctly in your example. If you simply want to display a horizontal line, you should use CSS (e.g. `border-top` on the `p`) instead.