# Separate rich snippet scopes for the same item

Tags: microdata, schema.org, rich-snippets

I am creating rich snippets for my webshop. One of the itemtypes I use is the "Organization" type. The problem with this is that I have specified the Organisation name and the image in the header of my webshop and the address in the footer. In between is the rest of the webshop with all it's products, reviews etc.

When I test my rich snippets with http://www.google.nl/webmasters/tools/richsnippets, I get two separate Organisations instead of one. Is there a way to combine my two scopes to become one Organisation?

Here is the situation I have right now:

```
<div id="header" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Webshopname</h1>
    <img id="logo" itemprop="logo" src="https://webshopurl/img/webshop-logo.png">
</div>

<div class="whole_article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Articlename</h1>
</div>

<div id="footer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <div id="address" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <div itemprop="streetAddress">Address 12</div>
        <div itemprop="postalCode">Postalcode</div> 
        <div itemprop="addressLocality">Locality</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don’t create several items about the same thing on the same page.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20245377/1591669)

[You can use the `itemref` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969585/1591669) to add properties to an item that are not nested in the same element:

```html
<div id="header" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemref="address">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Webshopname</h1>
    <img id="logo" itemprop="logo" src="https://webshopurl/img/webshop-logo.png">
</div>

<div class="whole_article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Articlename</h1>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="address" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <div itemprop="streetAddress">Address 12</div>
        <div itemprop="postalCode">Postalcode</div> 
        <div itemprop="addressLocality">Locality</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I first tried this solution it did not work the way I expected it to. But after searching for "itemref" I found this page which explains the solution in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186058/html5-microdata-itemref-to-another-itemscope-person-works-for-organization