# Schema.org microdata for marketplace

Tags: microdata, schema.org

For a marketplace, schema data becomes more confusing.  Not only will you want to represent your organization, but you also have the supplier's organization to worry about.  Is it bad practice to have all of this data on one page? Should the product page only have product information in the metadata, and the local business only have local business details on it?

Marketplace Org

- logo
- name
- description

LocalBusiness Org

- logo
- name
- description
- address
- lat/long
- product

  - description
  - rating
  - price

I can provide html for all of this, but I am not sure this needs it to explain. I read the schema docs pretty in-depth but it doesn't have great examples of what a marketplace site would do with multiple organizations or what Google will think of it.  For instance, if there is a localbusiness with many products, is it proper to have an aggregate rating on the localbusiness page of all of their products combined into one rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to have all of this data on one page?

No. [The more the better!](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54703/17633) (Of course it may be the case that some consumers only like to work with a single item per page, but when it comes to this topic, *anything* might be possible. So when you are interested in a particular consumer, you should consult their documentation.)

Every `itemscope` creates a new item. Every item on a page is (… should be) about something *different*.

So [don’t create several items for the same thing on the same page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/58460/17633) (unless you can use [`itemid`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21481289/1591669) so that it’s clear that the items are about the same thing).

If possible, use properties to relate the items.

- For example, [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) has the property [`makesOffer`](http://schema.org/makesOffer) to point "to products or services offered by the organization" (i.e., [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer)), or the property [`owns`](http://schema.org/owns) for products "owned by the organization" (i.e., [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product)).
- You can associate a [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) via [`brand`](http://schema.org/brand) or [`manufacturer`](http://schema.org/manufacturer) with an [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) (resp. [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness)).

Comment: So would I nest the data inside the other?  Organization would hold the local business inside of it?  Thats more-so the type of answer I am looking for.  How would this look hierarchically?

Comment: @Du3: It’s hard to discuss this without seeing your actual code + content. Generally, you’d nest it in such a way that it, well, makes sense (this might also depend on the available properties).