# Two or more Organization tags - the same organization

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I have two tags on my website (using Microdata):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  ...
</div>
```

This is because in website's header where is first tag is `itemprop="url"` and `itemprop="logo"`.

In footer is secand tag, and there are links to Facebook, Twitter, Google+, with `itemprop="sameAs"` attr.

Also social links are nofollow.

Is it correct or schould I put everything in to one `Organization` tag? Is it correct to have social links nofollow?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would use only one `Organization` item.

In Microdata, you could use the `itemref` attribute to add the properties from the footer to it ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21493483/1591669)).

If that’s not possible for some reason, you may want to convey that both `Organization` items are about the same organization. This could be done by adding `itemid` attributes (but that’s, strictly speaking, [not yet supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25410560/1591669) by Schema.org) with the same URI value to both items, or by providing properties that typically have unique values (for example, you could give the `Organization` in the footer also a `url` property, pointing to the same URL as the one in the header).

Comment: OK, thanks. What about `rel="nofollow"` attribute? Will robots read it as alternative links to my website?

Comment: @miszczu: As I noted in my edit (which you rolled back), you should not ask two questions in one question post, and the `nofollow` question is likely off-topic here on Stack Overflow, as it’s asking for SEO advice.