# Is it okay to repeat the same itemscope with additional properties for a single LocalBusiness?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I've used `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"` 3 times on the same page for the same property. I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do, but because my page structure has many different blocks and divs, and that's the only way I could get it work when testing with Google's Structured Data Testing Tool.

[image: Structured Data Testing Tool: output showing 3 LocalBusiness items]

Does it mean that Google thinks that this data is from 3 different businesses?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
<h3><span itemprop="name">My Business Name</span></h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="column mcb-column one-third column_column  column-margin-10px">
  <div class="column_attr align_center" style="">
    <h3>Darbo Laikas:</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column mcb-column one-third column_map ">
  <script>
    function google_maps_56c99fa96b132() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.718959, 25.302484);
      var draggable = true;
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        draggable: draggable,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google-map-area-56c99fa96b132"), myOptions);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
      });
    }
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      google_maps_56c99fa96b132();
    });
  </script>
  <div class="google-map-wrapper no_border">
    <div class="google-map" id="google-map-area-56c99fa96b132" style="width:100%; height:200px;">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column mcb-column one-third column_column  column-margin-">
  <div class="column_attr" style="">
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
      <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <i class="icon-location"></i><span itemprop="streetAddress"> 70 My street address</span>, <span itemprop="addressLocality">London</span>, <span itemprop="postalCode">09124</span>
        <br/>(Interjero centras "Klasikos Namai")
        <br/>
        <br/><i class="icon-phone"></i><a href="tel:+44 777 22222" itemprop="telephone">(8-777) 22222</a>
        <br/>
        <br/><i class="icon-mail"></i><a href="mailto:london@domain.com " itemprop="email">london@domain.com</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column mcb-column one-third column_opening_hours ">
  <div class="opening_hours">
    <div class="opening_hours_wrapper">
      <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>
              <time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo-Fr 10:00-18:00"></time>Monday - Friday</label><span>10:00–18:00</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>Saturday - Sunday</label><span>Uždaryta</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong because there are three LocalBusinesses on that page according to the markup.
You should use itemid so that all the itemscopes reference the same LocalBusiness.
Add `itemid="mybusiness"` to each itemscope.

[image]

Comment: thanks for an answer. Is there a difference of how I call my itemid? I've noticed that it adds this url: http://www.example.com/mybusiness, does it mean anything? Should I maybe call it the same as my page where the address is displayed?

Comment: @Mantas No, this doesn't mean anything as a URL — it's just an identifier. It doesn't matter what you call it, as long as you're consistent between the same LocalBusiness obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this means that there are three local businesses; they might describe the same entity, but a consumer can’t know for sure.

[grgarside’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35539323/1591669) suggests tot use the **`itemid` attribute**. By using this with the same URL value, you convey that these three `LocalBusiness` item describe the same entity.

There’s another solution for your case: the **`itemref` attribute**. This attribute allows you to add properties to an item (both on the same page) without having to nest them under the item‘s `itemscope`. This way you only have *one* `LocalBusiness` item:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" itemref="the-address the-openinghours">
    <h3 itemprop="name">My Business Name</h3>
</div>

<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" id="the-address">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress"> 70 My street address</span>, <span itemprop="addressLocality">London</span>, <span itemprop="postalCode">09124</span>
    <a href="tel:+44 777 22222" itemprop="telephone">(8-777) 22222</a>
    <a href="mailto:london@domain.com " itemprop="email">london@domain.com</a>
</div>

<time itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo-Fr 10:00-18:00" id="the-openinghours"></time>
```

A possible advantage of using `itemref` instead of `itemid` is that most (if not all) consumers support `itemref`, but the support of `itemid` is likely not that good. However, `itemref` only works if the item and the property are in the same document, while `itemid` works globally.

And strictly speaking, the vocabulary (Schema.org in this case) needs to claim to support global identifiers with `itemid`, [which Schema.org didn’t yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25410560/1591669). But practically this probably doesn’t matter.

Note that you can use both attributes: `itemref` to only have one item, `itemid` to give this item an identifier (which you or others can use to unambiguously identify the local business described by your `LocalBusiness` item within other documents).